# Casperjs doesn't work in windows 10

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I installed nodejs, python, phantomjs, casperjs.
But when I test with test script file as below. 
Path added to Environmental variables. 
Also version can be showed at any directory.

[Image Attached: Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7t9.jpg)
C:\Users>phantomjs --version
2.1.1

C:\Users>casperjs --version
1.1.4

C:\Users>cd jbm

C:\Users\JBM>cd Desktop

C:\Users\JBM\Desktop>casperjs.bat slmjstest.js
'casperjs.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\JBM\Desktop>casperjs slmjstest.js
CasperError: Can't find module capser

phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:307 in patchedRequire

```js
var casper = require('capser').create({verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"});


casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
    
casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
    
casper.run();
```

Comment: Please add your output as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled module name in your require.

var casper = require('ca`ps`er')

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"});
```

Also call the script with just `casperjs script.js`

Hope that helps!